# I can't pass a model to a view page , don't know why?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am absolute beginner with ASP.NET

I am watching some tutorials online

I have to pass a model to a view

the codes which used in the tutorials

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
     var model = new Resturant(12,"Huwaai");
     return new View(model);
}
```

View making error -> it is not defined/found

instead of these codes , I am using

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
     var model = new Resturant(12,"Huwaai");
     return new ViewResult();
}
```

these codes work , but not passing the models

when using return new ViewResult(model);

not working -> ViewResult does not take any parameters -_-

Comment: you might be missing some namespaces

Comment: Typically the return statement would be
`return View(model);` without `new` keyword.

Comment: Thanks @FrankWitte , solved now

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As mentioned by Frank White above, you are using the new keyword instead of returning the result of the View method defined in the Controller base class.